# My string is not equal to another string when it should be

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to compare a string to another string. This is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

int main()
{


    string verse = "Jn 3:30 Es nesesario que El cresca, pero que yo mengue.";

    string entverse;
    int opc;
    cin >> entverse;
    if (entverse == verse)
    {
        cout << "amen!";

    }
    else
    {
        cout << "oops!";
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

It is supposed to print **"amen"** when I write it right but it does not. Why?

Comment: `cin >> entverse;` reads a single word because it splits on whitespace. Use `getline(cin, entverse);`.

Comment: What do you get when you print both compared strings? This is called debugging and something useful to learn.

Comment: You're also missing the ability to do some basic debugging on your own. If you used a debugger to run your program one line at a time, and inspect the values of all variables, then you would've immediately seen the simple fact that there's only one word read into `entverse`.  It will be very difficult for you to learn C++ without learning some basic skills in debugging code.

Comment: try to print the input string (entverse) before compare it

Comment: im just a beginner but thanks for the advice

Comment: thanks i managed to fix it with  your help!! @Quentin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use getline instead of cin. Check out this documentation about getline.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/